# Why doesnt SQLite correctly identify the column type of a view when the column name is escaped?

Tags: sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE foo (  this            VARCHAR(64) );
CREATE VIEW far AS SELECT  this            FROM foo;
PRAGMA table_info(far) /* this correctly has VARCHAR(64) as the type */

CREATE TABLE bar ( 'this.is.a.test' VARCHAR(64) );    
CREATE VIEW baz AS SELECT 'this.is.a.test' FROM bar;
PRAGMA table_info(baz) /* this has no type for 'this.is.a.test' */
```

Tested with SQLite version 3.8.4.3

Comment: Does it matter? SQLite uses dynamic typing, and type affinity conversion (which is afaik the only thing that typing a column affects) only happens when you write values, which you can't do on views in SQLite anyway.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo it does because I use this type information to cast the input of the function. yes, there are workarounds, but I rather like not passing type information everywhere. E.g. A BLOB, String, and Integer are stored as different types internally and have to be bound in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).
Column types do not restrict the type or the length of values that can be stored in the column.

Column types are stored for compatibility with other databases, but they are a property of the *column*, not the *values* in the column, so there is no guarantee that the type information is kept when the value is taken out of the table (when you exeute a query, either directly on the table, or through a view).

Comment: Why then does it work when the name of the column of the original table is not escaped?

Comment: That value is not changed at all when read from the table. Handling the quotes changes it enough so that it loses the type information.